# Unable to locate image while changing backgroundImage from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my HTML, I have:

```
<img id="imgClickAndChange" class="myImgClass" (click)="replaceImage()"/>
```

In my CSS, I have following inside myImgClass:

```
background-image: url(images/myImg.svg);
```

And it works fine. Image myImg.svg is displayed.

CSS,images folder and HTML files all are in same folder.

Function 'replaceImage' does following:

```
replaceImage{
  const image = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange');
  image.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/myAnotherImg.svg)';
}
```

So, I basically aim to change the image on click.

But, this doesn't work. Image 'myAnotherImg.svg' is not found, though it's at same location as first image.

Error:

> http://localhost:4200/images/myAnotherImg.svg 404 (Not Found)

Why does this happen?

Comment: can you access `myAnotherImg.svg` directly?

Comment: I would always toggle classes to change the style.  It's a deadly sin of web development to define any styles in javascript! ;)  Who knows? It might even resolve your issue.

Comment: If you are using the angular web dev server, then you will need to add your "images" folder to the "assets" array in your angular.json file.

Comment: @JonDeWitt, how to toggle classes?

Comment: If you keep image as you have it defined there, you can do it like this: `image.classList.toggle('classToToggle')` or you can do `image.classList.add('classToAdd')` and `image.classList.remove('classToRemove')` if needed. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Toggle didn't work, but add/remove worked like a charm.

Comment: @Mandroid did you try to use $('#imgClickAndChange').css("background-image", "url(images/myAnotherImg.svg)");? or you don't want to use JQuery?

Comment: Try setting the second svg within the css page. If it fails on this attempt, look into any spelling mistakes.

Comment: @YoussefAliYoussef, jQuery is not an option for me.